# How do I observe DOM changes in an Angular/Jasmine unit test?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mutation-observers

I have an Angular 8 application that uses Jasmine and Karma for unit testing.

I have a fairly simple method that copies a string to the user's clipboard, and I am trying to unit test it. The method creates and destroys a temporary textarea as part of this copy process. I need to capture this textarea when it is created.

```
  copyToClipboard() {
    // Create a textarea to hold the string.
    const text = document.createElement('textarea');
    text.value = this.value;
    text.id = 'temporary_copy_area';
    document.body.appendChild(text);

    // Copy the contents of the textarea to the clipboard.
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");

    // Clean up.
    document.body.removeChild(text);
  }
```

I created a `MutationObserver` in the test's `beforeEach` and I'm observing the document body. I disconnect in the `afterEach`.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    observer = new MutationObserver((changes) => {
      console.log('observed an event');
    });
    observer.observe(document.body, {subtree: true, childList: true})
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    observer.disconnect();
  });
```

A simple test that just calls the SUT produces no log messages:

```
  it('should copy to the clipboard', () =>
  {
    component.copyToClipboard();
  });
```

I know the code is executing, because the test text does wind up in the clipboard.

If I comment out the `afterEach`, the observer stays connected and I'll see events if I manipulate the page.

I tried commenting out the `removeChild` in the copy method, just in case the events were being suppressed because they canceled out. That didn't help.

Comment: Test the **expected** behavior and not the *internal* workings of the function. If the text ends up on the clipboard, then the test should pass. You're finished.

Comment: Since I'm running in a browser, I can't look at the clipboard. The next-best solution I could come up with was to attach to the copy event of the textarea.

Comment: You can read the clipboard contents via the API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to make this a more correct unit test, but that's not going to work either. The clipboard API requires a user to accept the action, but this test will be running headless, in a pipeline, with no user. Besides which, there are times when I'm going to want to observe the DOM for a more proper test, and I really want to know why what I'm doing isn't working for that.